# ruby integer to boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a DB field that is integer type and values are always 0 or 1. How do I grab the equivalent boolean value in ruby? such that when i do the following the check box is set appropriately:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'resend', @system_config.resend %>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could use the `zero?` method. It returns true if 0. If you need to backwards, you could easily negate it to `!@system_config.resend.zero?`. Or you could extend the Fixnum class, adding a `to_b?` method, since everything is open and extensible in dynamic languages.

```
class Integer
  def to_b?
    !self.zero?
  end
end
```

[image]

Ruby API: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html#M001050

Comment: Thanks Jarret. 
Part of my solution was also to use the check_box_tag helper properly like so:
<%= check_box_tag 'resend', @system_config.resend, @system_config.resend %>

Comment: Note that there's also [`nonzero?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F) which may read better than `!zero?`.

Comment: I would very strongly recommend not adding functions to built-in classes. I come from a more javascript world where there are multiple times where that comes back to bite people, but more than just that: Everyone reading the code will know what `nonzero?` function is, but would have no idea what `to_b?` is!

Comment: Just be careful with `nonzero?` - it returns truthy and falsy values, but not `true` as `zero?` does (they are defined in different classes, see http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-zero-3F versus http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F

Comment: @chesterbr I agree. This just threw me for a loop right now. I looked up why `nonzero?` did not return a boolean as most ruby predicate methods do and came upon this ticket debating getting this corrected https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9123. Seems not everyone agrees this is an issue so it unfortunately doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Comment: I'm also interested in falsey/truthy values being converted to boolean with zero converting to false. So `!!x && x != 0` alternatively `!(!x || x == 0)`.

Answer (score 13):

1 is your only truth value here. So you can get the boolean truth value with `number == 1`.

Comment: Maybe this could be worded more clearly. I almost thought you meant this to be ruby standard. The accepted answer seem to give a ruby-standard-compatible solution, that happens to also fit with the actual question.

Comment: @Simon B.: I'm not sure what about my answer seems "non-standard" to you. Both the `==` and `zero?` methods are standard Ruby. But it so happens that `number == 1` reads more clearly than `!number.zero?` IMO.

Comment: In ruby, both 0 and 1 are "truthy", so actually there's no chance to make any answer here both "standard" and answer the question. Sorry. Maybe I better to try to get this into the question text or title. Anyone coming here looking for "ruby-faithful type casting" from Fixnum to Boolean will otherwise get confused either way. Also, according to http://drawingablank.me/blog/ruby-boolean-typecasting.html is seems !! is the only ruby-faithful option. Which is not an option in the question above.

Answer (score 4):

With Rails there's also `ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)` which makes `0` false, non-zero true, `[]` true, `{}` true. Note that `nil` -> `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and dealt with it this way:

```
def to_boolean(var)
  case var
    when true, 'true', 1, '1'
      return true
    when false, 'false', 0, '0'
      return false
  end
end
```

This works with forms, databases and people who don't know Ruby.
I found it to be useful especially with Rails, since parameters are often passed/interpreted as strings and I don't want to worry about that.

Comment: The indentation here is non-standard. Simpler form would be

def to_boolean(value)
  ['true',1,'1',true].include?(value)
end

Comment: `return` keyword is redundant here. Also you could use `else` case to return `false`.